# DotNetNuke 7.0+ Redirect Infinite Loop and 404 Errors

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I just recently migrated my website that I've developed locally over to a development server. When I opened up the website from the dev server, it goes into a infinite loop after logging in. All my links on the website are running into an 404 error and same with my modules.

The website works perfectly fine on my local machine, but not on the dev server.

I've searched for an answer for this on Google, and some say to update the "module" tag to "modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=”true”", but that doesn't work and I run into a 500 error.

For more information, I'm sitting my site on windows 2008 server and SQL 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to troubleshoot Infinite Loop problems on DNN I start by identifying what is the loop, i.e, which from and to which pages this is happening.

I do that with fiddler to trace the loop.

That may give you a clue into the problem.

I had a problem like that the other day and this is what I did. It helped me to troubleshoot.